# recursion difference in BST data Structure

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search-tree

here is BST code by java

> ```
> public class BST<Key extends Comparable<Key>,Value>{
> private Node root ; 
> private class Node{
>     private Key key;
>     private Value val;
>     private Node left,right;
>     private int n; 
>     public Node(Key key, Value val , int n){
>         this.key=key ; this.val=val; this.n=n;
>     }
> }
> public int size(){
>     return size(root);
> }
> private int size(Node x){
>     if(x==null) return 0 ; 
>     else return x.n;
> }
> public Value get(Node x, Key key){
>     if(x==null) return null;
>     int cmp = key.compareTo(x.key);
>     if(cmp<0) return get(x.left,key);
>     else if(cmp>0) return get(x.right,key);
>     else return  x.val;
> }
> public Value get(Key key){
>     return get(root,key);
> }
> public void put(Key key , Value val){
>     root = put(root,key,val);
> }
> public Node put(Node x ,Key key , Value val){
>     if(x==null) return new Node(key,val,1);
>     int cmp = key.compareTo(x.key);
>     if(cmp<0) x.left = put(x.left,key,value);
>     else if(cmp>0) x.right =put(x.right , key value);
>     else x.val = val;
>     x.n=size(x.left)+size(x.right)+1;
>     return  x;
> }
> }
> ```

1 I wonder, Method `put` and `get`   are all the recursive function ?
for me ,why `x.left=put(x.left,key,val)` ? can i delete   `x.left=` or replace it with `return put(x.left,key,val)`?

2 I wonder, in recursive function ,return statement is necessary ? 
for example in Fibonacci

```
`public static int recursiveFactorial(int n){
  if (n == 1) return 1;else return n * recursiveFactorial(n-1);
 } `
```

can I delete the second `return`?

Comment: No, if you specify a return type, you must return something.

Comment: I want to know :  what's happening on return statement in java?

Answer (score 0):

Why exactly do you want to delete code? If the code is from a Java source, its probably already at its least redundant stage. Deleting code will probably break it.

A return statement will return a variable that the function is designed to find.

```
public static int recursiveFactorial(int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return n * recursiveFactorial(n - 1);
    }
}
```

public static **int** recursiveFactorial(int n){..}

The int decalres that the function will return an integer value when called. It has an int parameter, which will only accept an integer. It then executes and returns a new integer.

```
 int n = recursiveFactorial(5);
```

A recursive function has two parts - base case and a recursive case. When the function is called with a number, say 5 it will continue to call itself until it gets to the base case (1)

recursiveFactorial(5) -> recursiveFactorial(4) -> recursiveFactorial(3) -> recursiveFactorial(2) -> recursiveFactorial(1) -> return 1 -> return 2 * 1 -> return 3 * (2 * 1) -> return 4 * (3 * 2 * 1) -> return 5 * (4 * 3 * 2 * 1) = 120

Comment: i know the funciton Factorialwill call itself before encountering  a base condition. But i still wonder in BST ,Can I replace the code 'x.left=put(x.left,key,val)'   with ' put(x.left,key,val)'